# Quantum representation of cube

Tags: quantum-state

Let's say I have a square matrix of size $2^n\times 2^n$ with entries being 8 bit integers, where $2^n\times 2^n=b\times b\times b=2^l\times 2^l\times 2^l$, then if I want to represent that matrix in the form of a cube, is the following representation correct?
$$|A\rangle=\dfrac{1}{2^{3k/2}}\sum_{i=0}^{2^l-1}\sum_{j=0}^{2^l-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^l-1}|A(i,j,k)\rangle\otimes |i\rangle|j\rangle|k\rangle,$$ where $A(i,j,k)$ is the value at the location $(i,j,k)$ and $|A(i,j,k)\rangle$ is the binary representation of the decimal value, and $|i\rangle,|j\rangle,|k\rangle$ are the position coordinates each of length $b$ bits. Can we represent the cube like this?

Comment: $2^9\times 2^9=2^6\times 2^6\times 2^6$, so here $b=64$,  yes binary representation means the binary of the number, for example, $7=|111\rangle $, associating a $ket$ with the binary representation, yes $A$ is the matrix with integer entries with each entry of $8$ bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, you essentially have a cube consisting of $2^l$ points along each direction, and associated with each point $(i,j,k)$ is an 8 bit integer $A(i,j,k)$?

In that case, a state of $3l+8$ qubits,
$$
|A\rangle=\frac{1}{2^{3l/2}}\sum_{i,j,k=0}^{2^l-1}|A(i,j,k)\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle|k\rangle
$$
is one possible way of representing the data. It is very reminiscent of [quantum fingerprinting](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0102001) schemes.

The real question is what you want to use such a representation for? That will determine if the representation is any good. What you cannot do is use single copies to deterministically extract information about the values of $A(i,j,k)$. This should be obvious - you cannot use $3l+8$ qubits to give you arbitrary access to $24l$ bits of data.

Comment: Yes that is the representation that i also wrote, except for the typo in the normalizing part. I didn't understand the last part of your answer?

Comment: Well, you question "Can I represent it like this?" is answered with a qualified "yes" (it contains all the data, but it depends on what you need to do with the data). I'm trying to check *why* you want to represent that data as a quantum state in order to determine if your chosen representation is any good for that purpose.

Comment: actually, i need this for information scrambling purpose.