# Large size of matrices for little outcome

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-state, classical-computing

I am stuck in a dilemma about how to proceed with a quantum computing algorithm that changes the original state of a system to another.

Say I have a superposition of all $8$ bit integer values that are stored in the form of a $256\times 256$ matrix $A$. In total I would then need $8+16=24$ qubits to represent the matrix, with the first $8$ qubits representing the value in binary i.e $x\in \{0,1\}^8$ and similarly with index needing $8+8$ qubits.

Suppose I write this matrix in a uniform superposition of all the initial states. If I don't want to perform any operation on this matrix; I need to multiply it with a unitary matrix of size $ 2^{24}\times 2^{24}$.

Implementing such a huge matrix on classical computers just to do technically nothing seems weird.  Does quantum computing just theorize this concept for the future? Is merely writing this sufficient when I use classical methods?

Comment: A matrix of 256x256 dimension is represented by 8 qubits, reverse is more accurate though. I am not sure where you getting 24 from.

Comment: 8 qubits for the value at position $( x,y)$,  $ 8$  for the x coordinate ,$ 8$for the y coordinate. so that makes a total of 24 qubits

Comment: The state representing all 8 bit superposition is of dimemsion 256x256. I don't get why and how you want to represent the same state with 24 qubits now. Maybe show more maths or go step by step in your question.

Comment: it is shown in this question https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/quantum-representation-of-cube

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here, to be honest - As @Hemant said, you have an 8 bit number (requiring 8 qubits to store, regardless of whether you're putting them in superposition or not). I'm not sure what you mean by an 'index' here and if you then multiply it by a unitary matrix, then you're implementing some circuit on those qubits (depending on the matrix), so I'm not sure how that means you're doing nothing - would you be able to elaborate on these points further or take a step back and ask the first small specific part that you don't understand and we can go from there?

Comment: an element say $A(i,j)\in \{0,1,...255\}$ Now how do i get access to that element, i need the location of that element given by $(i, j)$ where $ i\in \{0,1,...255\}$ and $j \in \{0,1,...255\}$, how many qubits do we require to completely specify the matrix element?

Comment: $8$ qubits, $A(i,j)=\langle i|A|j\rangle$ where if the binary representation of the number $i\in \{0,1,\dots,255\}$ is $x_0 \dots x_7$ then $|i\rangle=|x_0\rangle\otimes\dots\otimes |x_7\rangle$

Comment: Is the overarching question here if it is necessary to use a full 256x256 matrix if simulating 8 qubits on a classical computer? Or why are you bringing in classical computing here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about what you want to do with a $256\times 256$ matrix of integers $[0,1,\cdots, 255]$.

You can create a uniform superposition by Hadamard'ing $24$ separate qubits, and consider your system as the adjacency matrix of a $256$-vertex directed graph, where vertices can be connected with an edge weighted with an integer between $0$ and $2^8-1=255$.

But remember your superposition of $24$ qubits is then over **all possible** such graphs.  When you measure your superposition, you would be drawing from all $2^{24}$ such graphs.

It sounds like you want to focus on a *particular* instance - e.g., you know your graph already.  But then it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.